# Debian 10 random (apparently) freezing

Tags: debian, freeze

I recently upgraded my Debian 9 to Debian 10, and ever since, I have been experiencing random freezing. The screen just freezes, and apparentyl the kayboard and the mouse too (for instance, the CapsLock light won't turn on/off).

I noticed that it won't freeze while it's not being used, sleeping, but when I'm using it. Sometimes it goes for almost an hour without freezing, other times it takes only a few minutes since I start using it.

One of the times it froze, I had htop running, and there was no CPU overloading (all cores where working under 15%) and the memory was fairly free.

I have reinstalled the system from scratch twice, and the freezing continues.

The PC has only one system installed, Debian 10.

**`lscpu` output:**

```
$ lscpu
Arquitectura:                        x86_64
modo(s) de operación de las CPUs:    32-bit, 64-bit
Orden de los bytes:                  Little Endian
Tamaños de las direcciones:          48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                              6
Lista de la(s) CPU(s) en línea:      0-5
Hilo(s) de procesamiento por núcleo: 2
Núcleo(s) por «socket»:              3
«Socket(s)»                          1
Modo(s) NUMA:                        1
ID de fabricante:                    AuthenticAMD
Familia de CPU:                      21
Modelo:                              2
Nombre del modelo:                   AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
Revisión:                            0
CPU MHz:                             1406.161
CPU MHz máx.:                        3500,0000
CPU MHz mín.:                        1400,0000
BogoMIPS:                            7031.50
Virtualización:                      AMD-V
Caché L1d:                           16K
Caché L1i:                           64K
Caché L2:                            2048K
Caché L3:                            8192K
CPU(s) del nodo NUMA 0:              0-5
Indicadores:                         fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
```

**`lspci` output:**

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
```

**`lsscsi` output:**

```
$ lsscsi
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      KINGSTON SHFS37A BBF0  /dev/sda 
[5:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD5000AAKX-0 1H15  /dev/sdb 
[6:0:0:0]    disk    Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 PMAP  /dev/sdd 
[7:0:0:0]    disk    Multi    Flash Reader     1.00  /dev/sdc
```

**`lsblk` output:**

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 107,2G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   4,6G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465,8G  0 part /home
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Try to ssh into it, to see if this is a full freeze or not.

Comment: Try also to boot from a Debian 10 USB key, to see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I managed to ssh into it from another computer.

Comment: I have the same behavior on a Asus UX305 laptop. No clue on the origin for now. And very random. What computer do you have?

Comment: If you use Gnome, try [switching back from Wayland to Xorg](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#wayland-by-default-on-gnome) and see if that helps. If you still experience freezes, try booting the stretch kernel (4.9) and see if that helps.

Comment: I installed Debian 9 and so far there were no problems (two weeks and running).

Comment: @franciscosollima have you had any luck with this? I am seeing a similar issue on my server running Debian 10. No freezes on Debian 9 either. Installing the non-free firmware or the intel microcode hasn't helped.

Comment: To be honest, after I downgraded I never tried again to upgrade it. I'm now currently using Debian 10 on a different computer and it's working good so far.

Answer (score 1):

With my UX 305, I decided to do a fresh install of Buster and it was still freezing. So I installed intel-microcode and firmware-misc-nonfree. Since then, I haven't seen a freeze in 48 hours and I am very hopeful!

Comment: I installed Debian 9 and so far there were no problems (two weeks and running)

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue sporadically with Debian 10 on a Lenovo system too old for any BIOS/UEFI update support. Based on https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode, I did the following for my system:

1. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Add `contrib non-free` to all `deb` and `deb-src` lines. For example: 
   `deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main` *`contrib non-free`* 
   `deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main` *`contrib non-free`*
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt install intel-microcode` *Note: Use `amd64-microcode` instead if appropriate*
5. Reboot to activate the microcode update

The microcode update will be applied only if the kernel or user-space utilities determine the update is required. The microcode package must remain installed for the microcode update to remain active.