# Debian Buster Freezing when Compiling Large Project

Tags: debian, freeze, compiler

I've recently begun encountering an issue when attempting to compile a moderately large software project where my entire computer freezes. I can't get to another tty, I can't move the mouse. After some experimentation, I was able to replicate this freezing with other compilers and large projects so I don't suspect this issue is particular to my code or compiler. From what I can tell, the issue does appear to occur primarily when some other software (either a IDE linter, browser, etc.) is also taking up a fair amount of CPU.

I've run `top` while inducing a freeze, and I will see two processes (one compiler and the "other") nearing 100% CPU, but neither process is actually using that much memory (at least according to top before it freezes). When the freeze occurs, the disk indicator light on my tower goes solid.

Having looked into various potential fixes online related to memory, but none of the below seemed to work:

- Deactivate swapping
- Decrease swappiness
- Increase required free RAM

At present, I'm simply at a loss for what to do. I'm not even sure of what logs I can check or ways I can know the true cause of the unresponsiveness. Any and all assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try a long stress test of your hardware - especially disk, RAM. Try running the compile with nothing else running.

Comment: Using other compilers all of which generate the same problem doesn't eliminate a problem with your code - it eliminaates a problem with the compiler.

Comment: @CinaedSimson To clarify, I am able to make it freeze with sufficiently large projects other than my own. If memory serves, when compiling LLVM LDC2 (the project, not compiling with ldc2 but compiling ldc2 itself) I got the same lockup.

Comment: @JeremyBoden Compiling with nothing else running will generally work just fine.I will download a stress-tester and see about stressing out specific faculties of the system. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I may be encountering this when compiling GHCJS. The freeze reliably occurs with this commit  https://github.com/peterbecich/codeworld/commit/4d92359bd22a4a52f1a9074283e97b1e4a603367 and `nix build -f default.nix`

Comment: This looks promising: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615500/195308

Comment: Also similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681552/seemingly-random-freezes-after-update-to-debian-bullseye?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: In my case, upgrading from kernel 5.10 to backported kernel 5.14 produced a better error. Instead of freezing the system, a segmentation fault is printed to the console.