# Seemingly random freezes after update to Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian, upgrade, debugging, freeze

About two months ago I updated my laptop (Asus Zenboox UX303LA) from Debian Buster to Bullseye. This involved a kernel update to Linux 5.10 (the problem persists on 5.10.84-1, which is current stable). I never had any problems with random freezes before the update. After the update I have been running updates on a regular basis.

Since the update, it occasionally happens that the system freezes entirely. I cannot switch to a tty with Ctrl-Alt-Fx and REISUB does not do anything either. I can only force-shutdown the system and restart.

This is very annoying. I have had it happen on two occasions now that a .git directory got corrupted because of the forced restart.

Observations:

- This can happen up to several times a day, and sometimes does not happen with an uptime of several days.
- It does not seem to be related to any particular program.
- It also happens when there is enough free RAM.
- It is unrelated to CPU usage.
- It *might* be more frequent when there is a lot of disk IO (e.g. when building a docker image), but also seems to happen when there is not a lot of disk IO (unless there is something going on in the background at that moment, which I find unlikely given my installation).
- `kern.log`, `messages`, `syslog`, and `user.log` do not contain any information at the moment of the freeze.
- Based on the suggestions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535418/505344) I have installed `intel-microcode` (the processor now uses microcode revision 0x2f from November 12, 2019) and `firmware-misc-nonfree`, but the problem persists.
- `netconsole` does not log any kernel messages (with options `debug ignore_loglevel`) prior to the freeze; the last message is `Sent WATCHDOG=1 notification`, but this gets sent all the time (not always followed by a freeze).

I know absolutely nothing about the kernel and different versions, but given that REISUB doesn't work I would expect that the problem lies there(?) And since the problem arose directly after updating to Bullseye I think it's safe to assume that this is not a hardware problem (e.g. with the SSD), but perhaps a driver issue(?) How can I further debug this issue?

Comment: You could check if this can be related to GPU (even a browser uses WebGL nowadays). As this model probably has 2 GPUs (i-intel and d-nvidia) you could check if forcing the use of integrated intel if not used before or the use of discrete nvidia (with nouveau or with non-free nvidia) if not used before changes the rate of freezes. Alas it's one possibility among several other completely different. It can help to check if when frozen it can still answer pings. Also setting up network console logs to a 2nd (*nix) system could help.  See https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/netconsole.

Comment: @A.B thanks for your suggestions! I will set up netconsole and try to ping next time this happens and report back. My model only has an integrated GPU, is there then a way to find out if this is a likely cause? (Maybe a stress test?)

Comment: which exact version of the 5.10 kernel do you have installed?  Run `dpkg -l 'linux-image*' | grep '^.i'`.    I can't remember what version Bullseye released with, but it currently has 5.10.17+1.   If your kernel is older than that, try upgrading.   Alternatively, you could install 5.14.9+2~bpo11+1 from backports (but if you're using any dkms modules like ZFS or the proprietary nvidia driver, you'll probably have to upgrade them to the version in backports too - btw for more info about the backports repo, see https://backports.debian.org/).

Comment: @cas that command gives me both linux-image-4.19.0-18-amd64 (4.19.208-1) and linux-image-5.10.0-9-amd64 (5.10.70-1). That's not the version you mention, but `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` is a no-op at the moment. According to `uname -r` I'm on the latter. In any case I will install the kernel from backports and see what happens.

Comment: looks like you have 5.10.70, which is the latest available 5.10 kernel for stable (but according to https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/linux-signed-amd64, 5.10.84 should be in stable soon).  I would leave the backported 5.14 kernel as a last resort, if you can't solve the problem any other way.   There's nothing wrong with installing stuff from backports, but the combination of stable plus selected packages from backports hasn't been tested anywhere near as much as the stable release (and also tends to defeat the purpose of a long-lived stable release).

Comment: @A.B `netconsole` doesn't seem to give anything, unfortunately. The last message is `Sent WATCHDOG=1 notification`, but it's not immediately prior to the freeze and gets sent relatively frequently, most of the time not followed by a freeze. I still have to try pinging. If you have any other ideas I would be very grateful.

Comment: @cas I tried the backported kernel but it didn't resolve the problem, unfortunately. It also still happened under the new kernel in stable (5.10.84), and `netconsole` (suggested above) didn't give new information either. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: In my case (described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663704/debian-buster-freezing-when-compiling-large-project?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1292269_663704), upgrading from kernel 5.10 to backported kernel 5.14 produced a better error. Instead of freezing the system, a segmentation fault is printed to the console.